# How can I get object from join table with ManyToMany relationship? Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hql, join

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Coupon> coupons;
}

@Entity
public class Coupon {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "coupons")
private Collection<Customer> customers;
}
```

There are three tables in database: `customer`, `coupon` and `customer_coupons`, customer can purchase coupon and after purchasing table `customer_coupons` saves `customers_id` and `coupons_id` (Customer can have many coupons and coupon can have many customers).

I need somehow to get coupon of the customer by `customerId` and `couponId` from `customer_coupons` table. I have interface `CouponRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface CouponRepository extends JpaRepository<Coupon, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Coupon c WHERE c.id IN (SELECT coupons.id FROM customer_coupons WHERE coupons_id = ?1 AND customer_id = ?2)")
    Coupon findCustomerCoupon(int couponId, int customerId);
}
```

But this one query doesn't work, I get `QuerySyntaxException: customer_coupons is not mapped`. Can somebody help me to create the right query?

Comment: I think the point is, have to use jpa query language and not the real sql. There is no entity named "customer_coupons". You have to define the relationships by using a table "customer_coupons" but in the queries you don't use this table any more, just use Coupon.customers

Comment: @fairtrax yes, I understood that, but still can’t find the right query in JPQL. I’ll try what you recommend.

Comment: `select coupon from Customer c join c.coupons coupon where c.id = :customerId and coupon.id = :couponId`. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: @JBNizet thank you very much! This is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT coupon FROM Customer c JOIN c.coupons coupon WHERE c.id = :customerId AND coupon.id = :couponId

Answer from JB Nizet